# Changing long date format in C#

Tags: c#, devexpress

I am using devexpress 17.2 dateedit component on xtraReport as a parameter. How do I format a date such as "Mon Jul 15 2019 00:00:00 GMT +0300 (East Africa Time) that i get in my controller as a parameter value?

### Controller

```
String sDate = Request. Param[" startdate"].ToString();
DateTime startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(startdate);
```

It throws an error of

> "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime".

Comment: Did you try using DateTime.Parse? you can specify format option

Answer (score 1):

You can use DateTime.TryParseExact and use the format you want to convert .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string s = "Mon Jul 15 2019 00:00:00 GMT +0300 ";
                DateTime t;
                DateTime.TryParseExact(s,
                       "ddd MMM dd yyyy h:mm:ss GMT +0300 ",
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                       DateTimeStyles.None,
                       out t);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //Log exception
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could tweak the code a little, keep the date and time formatting and drop the timezone.

String sDate = Request.Param["startdate"].ToString("ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzz");

DateTime startDate =  DateTime.ParseExact(sDate, "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);